# How to dissolve a cluster in MAPBOX on click?

Tags: android, algorithm, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I have made a cluster similar to this https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/dds/ImageClusteringActivity.java

And i want to get the cluster to get dissolved into the single markers on click and set the camera to a proper zoom and position such that each markers is visible.
Right now i am only using -> **mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures()**   to get the no of points in the cluster and providing a zoom based on that. But that is not very effective.
Is there any method like getClusterExpansionZoom() for android ?

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: getClusterExpansionZoom is an upcoming feature. PR for that in https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/12727

Comment: what is the estimated time for this feature ?  And is there any other approach till then. thanks